# How can I add a line to multiple files in a directory tree structure?

Tags: text-processing, files

Adding a line to multiple files in the same structure is not very hard, but I am stumped on how to do it over a possibly large directory tree structure.  So lets say we have your project directory, which has hundreds of projects in it and you want to add a header to every *.c file. How can this be done?  remember the files could be quite deep.

Answer (score 8):

```
find ~/foldername -type f -name "*.c" -exec sed -i '1 i addtexthere' {} \;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: can you paste few  *.c lines of code

Comment: They are empty files.

Comment: `sed -i '1 i addtexthere'` does not work on empty files!